# Making inner html content jump down instead of outer one

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have days of the week, and timestamps which can be in any number[image]

When timestamps number increases or we shrink the browser, the expected behavior is to make timestamps jump down like this [image]

However, the behavior is like this [image]

Here is my simplified HTML codes for one day; Monday

```
<div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary days">
         Monday
         <span class="sprite-1-arrow-black-right"></span>
     </button>
     <div class="timestamps">
         <div class="timestamp">
             00:00 am - 00:00 pm
          </div>
          <div class="timestamp">
            00:00 am - 00:00 pm
           </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

in simplified css/sass

```
.days {
        display: inline-block;
}
.timestamps {
       display:inline-block;
}
.timestamp {
       display: inline-block;
}
```

I think, there should be flex solution, but I don't know how!

Comment: I'd say you're looking for `flex-wrap`, so `.form-group` with `no-wrap` and `.timestamps` with `wrap`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap everything in a flex container. By default it will have `flex-wrap: nowrap`.

Then wrap your timestamps in a nested flex container. Give this container `flex-wrap: wrap`.

Now the primary container *does not* wrap, but the timestamp items *will wrap*.

```css
.form-group {
  display: flex;
}

.timestamps {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

button {
  align-self: flex-start; /* override `stretch` default */
}

.timestamp {
  white-space: nowrap;    /* prevent text nodes from wrapping */
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary days">
    Monday
    <span class="sprite-1-arrow-black-right"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="timestamps">
    <div class="timestamp">00:00 am - 00:00 pm</div>
    <div class="timestamp">00:00 am - 00:00 pm</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/s3nkywha/3/)

Comment: this once is nice! there is one problem. there is one problem in my side. I dont want any changes in button or timestamp sizes. After apply this css I see that button sizes/days are changing where I specifically gave values to width and height

Comment: You may need to set *flex-shrink* to 0 on the flex items. Otherwise, comment back with a demo of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to use flex ?
The flow of the document is the naturaly going from top to bottom for blocks.

The solution is not to write more styles but less code:

```
.days {
  display: inline-block;
}
.timestamps {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gXGBZO

Writing unecessary code should always be avoided: it makes your project less maintanable, harder to understand and can also hinder performance (using complex layout can augment your reflow/repaint time)

Comment: my team lead loves flex, anything I write he asks for changing to flex solution :)

Comment: the solution looks nice, but I need the stamps to be side by side until they reach the maximum space, this solution put all time stamps stacked on top on each other in the first place :)

Comment: In this case flex seems more justified.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, where you have an equal width on the left buttons, the old BFC trick using `float`/`overflow: hidden`, combined with `inline-block` will solve that.

For anyone who can't use Flexbox (to support older browsers), this one will help.

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/s3nkywha/4/)

Stack snippet

```css
.days {
  float: left;
  width: 80px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}
.timestamps {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: 100px;  
}
.timestamp {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary days">
    Monday
    <span class="sprite-1-arrow-black-right"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="timestamps">
    <div class="timestamp">00:00 am - 00:00 pm</div>
    <div class="timestamp">00:00 am - 00:00 pm</div>
  </div>
</div>
```